# Optimizing dockerfile image size. What more & how can i reduce size of this image?

Tags: docker, optimization, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

Its my first question so *hello world*

So i'am beginner, unfortunately in both GNU/Linux and dockerizing things.
I got an image that reason to exist is having all in one image for  bitbucket-pipelines and azure-pipelines. (Multi-project image).

During forced update (added groovy and changed nodejs source due to problems with ssl) Image size went up form 1GB to 1.5GB.

With my tweaks i managed to free 150MB to current 1.35GB

**My tweeks**

- adding some rm
- apt-get clean
- npm cache clean
- merged many layers to as few as i could done

CURRENT DOCKERFILE

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
WORKDIR ~/
USER root
ARG USERNAME=root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install locales \
        build-essential \
        git \
        maven \
        ant \
        unzip \
        python3 \
        zip \
        wget \
        apt-transport-https \ 
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        software-properties-common \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_VERSION jdk-12.0.2+10
RUN set -eux; \
    ARCH="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; \
    case "${ARCH}" in \
       aarch64|arm64) \
         ESUM='855f046afc5a5230ad6da45a5c811194267acd1748f16b648bfe5710703fe8c6'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_aarch64_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       armhf) \
         ESUM='9fec85826ffb7b2b2cf2853a6ed3e001b528ed5cf13e435cd13026398b5178d8'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       ppc64el|ppc64le) \
         ESUM='4b0c9f5cdea1b26d7f079fa6478aceebf1923c947c4209d5709c0869dd71b98f'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_ppc64le_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       s390x) \
         ESUM='9897deeaf7a2c90374fbaca8b3eb8e63267d8fc1863b43b21c0bfc86e4783470'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_s390x_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       amd64|x86_64) \
         ESUM='1202f536984c28d68681d51207a84b6c76e5998579132d3fe1b8085aa6a5f21e'; \
         BINARY_URL='https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk12-binaries/releases/download/jdk-12.0.2%2B10/OpenJDK12U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_12.0.2_10.tar.gz'; \
         ;; \
       *) \
         echo "Unsupported arch: ${ARCH}"; \
         exit 1; \
         ;; \
    esac; \
    curl -LfsSo /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz ${BINARY_URL}; \
    echo "${ESUM} */tmp/openjdk.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    mkdir -p /opt/java/openjdk; \
    cd /opt/java/openjdk; \
    tar -xf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz --strip-components=1; \
    rm -rf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz;
        
ENV JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/openjdk" \
    PATH="/opt/java/openjdk/bin:$PATH" \
    ANT_HOME="/usr/share/java/apache-ant" \
    PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin" \
    GROOVY_HOME="/$USERNAME/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.8" \
    PATH="$PATH:/$USERNAME/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.8/bin"

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -f \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io"  | bash \
    && yes | /bin/bash -l -c "source $HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh \
    && sdk install groovy \
    && rm -rf $HOME/.sdkman/archives/* \
    && rm -rf $HOME/.sdkman/tmp/*" \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && npm install -g lodash \
    && npm install -g sfdc-generate-package \
    && npm install -g jsforce \
    && npm cache clean --force

#TESTS
CMD echo "print env varaibles: "  && printenv \
    && echo "XXX PATHS: "  && echo "$PATH  \n" \
    && echo "GROOVY_HOME " && echo "$GROOVY_HOME " \
    && echo "HOME " && echo "$HOME " \
    && echo "XXX SOFTWARE VERSIONS:" \
    && echo "nodejs :" && nodejs -v \
    && echo "npm :" && npm -v \
    && git --version \
    && ant -version \
    && python3 --version \
    && java -version \
    && groovy -version
```

DOCKER HISTORY

````
IMAGE               CREATED BY                                      SIZE
d7f3822f32da        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo…   0B
7f2f0f621ae8        |1 USERNAME=root /bin/sh -c curl -fsSL https…   413MB
a03ee701466f        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/o…   0B
8f3a9e1ce43c        |1 USERNAME=root /bin/sh -c set -eux;     AR…   350MB
ae7b362dfaee        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_VERSION=jdk-12.0…   0B
72fc4ae7e73f        |1 USERNAME=root /bin/sh -c apt-get update &…   521MB```
````

Comment: A Docker container usually runs a single program.  What is the single program this image will eventually run?  Does it need Python, Java, _and_ Node, all at the same time, to run the single application?

Comment: @DavidMaze indeed. it does not run a single application, its used on 2 projects right now  as a base for deploying. Soo on one project i need to have  java, ant, python, git and jsforce and on the other one i don't need python but i need groovy. I understood that i should apply single responsibility principle nevertheless being used for same purpose and having same core?

Comment: Don't even think at a _project_ level but a _program_ level.  If one project has a Java/Ant component and a Python component, and the other project is only a Java/Groovy project, you can have three separate Dockerfiles building three separate single-program images.  Since you're concerned about image size here, one program won't need the build system for the languages it's not using, and you can use techniques like multi-stage builds to remove the build system from the final images entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to make your Docker Image smaller.
Looking at your example 2 thing come to mind:

1. Try to create an Image in more than one Stage. Take the tools you need to creating the image in one Stage and create the last version of the container by only copying files from the previous Stages.
   See [Docker documentation on MultiStage Containers](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)
2. You are taking a Ubuntu image, which if very large. Better to take Alpine in the last Stage
3. In that Ubuntu container you are setting up the whole application (Python, Maven, Java).
   This is not the philosophy of Docker.  Better to create an Image for every service. Python-container, Java-container, etc. And with this setup try to stick to standard images.
   The moment you need to do apt-get in a container you need to think where you went wrong and how you can split it up in different containers.
4. For the different containers talking to each other, use docker-compose.

Comment: The difference between an Ubuntu and an Alpine image is pretty small compared to the space required by multiple language runtimes, the C build toolchain, and any C development libraries you're installing.  I'd change that base distribution as the very last step, and even then it might not save that much space.